# Can I invest in GLBSE on GLBSE?

Tags: glbse

With the new design it's starting to take off. I want in on GLBSE itself, is this possible or are there any plans for it to happen?

Comment: GLBSE has closed.

Answer (score 3):

GLBSE (or BitcoinGlobal, to be exact) has shares, but the shares aren't managed on GLBSE yet and the current bylaws prevent the shareholders from selling shares to non-shareholders without a majority vote. Moving the shares to GLBSE is planned, and I expect public trading to be allowed eventually.

(I'm treasurer of BitcoinGlobal and a shareholder.)

Comment: I find it quite shady for GLBSE not to be listed on GLBSE itself, like if they didn't fully trust their own system.

Comment: @Lohoris BitcoinGlobal shares existed before GLBSE did, so they couldn't initially be listed. It was planned to move them to GLBSE ASAP, but few of the shareholders cared to use GLBSE's previous terrible system. Now that GLBSE is easy to use, all of the shareholders should be able to sign up and have their shares credited to them.